# MATLAB Code: Sum of raised planes is off by a factor of two. WHY?

Tags: matlab

This code is meant to sum a bunch of planes that add up to half an ellipsoid. Then I multiply it by 2 ... but even when multiplied by 2, it's giving me HALF the volume of the ellipsoid.

What is going on?? Can you find my mistake? :)

```
Q_in = input            ('Please enter the rate of magma flow into dike in [m^3s^-1]: ');
t_flow_days = input     ('Please enter the amount of time magma is flowing into the dike in [days]: ');
t_flow_seconds = t_flow_days * 24 * 3600;               % Flow time converted to seconds 
% This sums a number of planes to simulate the volume of the dyke as a
% function of time. 

V_Dike_t = (Q_in.*t_flow_seconds);          % V in the ellipsoid at t 
pi = 3.14159265359;                         % Value of pi
c_axis_d = 2000;                            % ellipsoidal axis "c" (m)
b_axis_d = 250;                             % ellipsoidal axis "b" (m)
a_axis = (3*V_Dike_t)/(4*pi*b_axis_d*c_axis_d)  % a-axis fxn of volume (m) 
a_axis_d = a_axis;                          % a-axis fxn of V (m)

nSlices                 =   1e6; % defines the # of intervals or contours
verticalStep            =   c_axis_d./nSlices; 
largerRadiusStep        =   b_axis_d./nSlices; 
smallerRadiusStep       =   a_axis_d./nSlices;
sliceLargerRadius       =   b_axis_d; 
sliceSmallerRadius      =   a_axis_d;
V_of_Half_ellipsoid     =   0;
for sliceIndex          =   1:nSlices
    sliceArea           =   pi * sliceLargerRadius * sliceSmallerRadius;
    sliceVolume         =   sliceArea * verticalStep;
    sliceLargerRadius   =   sliceLargerRadius - largerRadiusStep;
    sliceSmallerRadius  =   sliceSmallerRadius - smallerRadiusStep;
    V_of_Half_ellipsoid =   V_of_Half_ellipsoid + sliceVolume;
end
finalVolume =   V_of_Half_ellipsoid*2;          
finalVolume_km =   finalVolume * 0.000000001; 

V_flow_km3 = V_Dike_t*0.000000001
V_dyke_km3 = finalVolume_km
```

Comment: I really think you'd be better off doing this by numerical integration in Matlab, implementing the math as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366238/using-cavalieris-principle-to-find-the-volume-of-an-ellipsoid

Comment: Well, the reason I've approached it this way is to integrate it with a solution for an expanding fluid as a function of depth ... so each "elliptical raised plane" will have a unique expansion value. I just can't figure out where my geometry is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The radii of the slices in an ellipsoid don't vary linearly - that may be your problem. What I've done in the code below is to calculate the x- and y-Radii as arcs based on the z-position. Note that everything can essentially be scaled linearly from the unit-sphere in the x, y, and z-directions. I've also "vectorized" the code so that all the volumes are calculated in one line instead of in a for-loop.

```
nSlices = 1e6;
unitSpacing = 1 / nSlices;
unitVector = linspace(0, nSlices, 1 - unitSpacing);
unitArc = sqrt(1 - unitVector.^2);

zSpacing = zRadius * unitSpacing;

xRadii = xRadius .* unitArc;
yRadii = yRadius .* unitArc;

sliceVolumes = zSpacing .* pi .* xRadii .* yRadii;

halfVolume = sum(sliceVolumes);
```